# What is the regular expression to match all text after a certain character?

Tags: javascript, regex

I know this question has been asked many times but those examples aren't working for me.

I'm trying to get the minute part of time in a single regular expression. What I have is:

```
minute = new RegExp(":[0-9]{1,2}").exec(time).toString().replace(":", "");
```

How can I get this done without using the .replace?

Comment: What does the `time` variable refer to?

Comment: @999, I guess time contains something like `18:28`

Comment: Why not split by `:`...?

Comment: Do you need to use a regex? Sounds like using a sledgehammer to drive a brad. Instead, how about: 1)Split on ":", take the right half. 2)Parse `"T"+time` into a `DateTime` and get its minutes.

Comment: time can be military or civilian time. examples are 18:28, 6:28PM, 6:28 PM, 6:28AM, etc.

Comment: @lc. Agreed, this is how I answered. If you're dealing with date/time, treat it like date/time data, not like a string. This is also why you don't use RegEx to parse HTML -- too many variables. Treat time like time, treat HTML like HTML, save the RegEx for when there isn't a more appropriate tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a capture group to get only what you want.

```
var time = '12:29',
    minute = /:([0-9]{1,2})/.exec(time)[1];

// minute is "29"
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming time is of the format `NN:NN` then the minutes can be extracted like so:

```
minute = time.match(/\d{2}$/)[0];
```

Or a simple split:

```
minute = time.split(':')[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Store "time" as a [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object, if you aren't already doing that. Then you can use [getMinutes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMinutes) to pull the minutes component out.

```
minute = time.getMinutes();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `time` is a time string like "10:15 AM", you can (and should) use the Date object. This is the right tool for the job, it is more flexible because it is made to deal with date/time data.

```
var time = '10:15 AM';
// handle either a full date string OR a time string
var d = new Date(time);
if (isNaN(d.getTime()))
    var d = new Date('1/1/2012 '+time);
```

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/gsg8X/

Probably better than trying to determine if the seconds are there or not, which could break a regular expression, or make it more complicated than it needs to be. I think you're better off using a date/time related tool to parse date/time related data.

**Documentation**

- `Date` on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of position anchor to grab the last part of the string

```
(/:([0-9]{1,2}$)/)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
minute = new RegExp(":([0-9]{1,2})").exec(time)[1];
```

This will match the whole thing, but store whatever the part in parenthesis matches for you to use later. Hence the `[1]`.

---

---

Going to leave the following in here, in case somebody comes looking for a non-javascript answer.

**This will not work in javascript, as it does not support lookbehinds.** Thanks @999.

Try using a positive lookbehind. That way you won't even need to replace :)

```
minute = new RegExp("(?<=:)[0:9]{1,2}").exec(time).toString();
```

`[0:9]{1,2}` is the pattern you actually want to match. `(?<=:)` just makes sure it has a colon behind it, without actually consuming anything.

Comment: JavaScript does not support lookbehinds in regular expressions.

Comment: Surprised at the number of downvotes while I was in the process of editing. Oh well.

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt Two? I removed mine, not really a big deal.

Comment: @Chris yeah, I wasn't worried about it. I was just surprised that they didn't show up *until* I edited the question, lol